# JOOQ - Conditional mapping to object if null

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

I want to achieve something like this. is this possible?

```
context.select(
 when(PRE_PLEADING.ID.isNull(), value((Object) null))
 .otherwise(row(PRE_PLEADING.ID,
                PRE_PLEADING.TITLE,
).mapping(ReceivedPleadingSummary::new)))
.from(...)
```

Im getting jOOQ; bad SQL grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a task to review much of jOOQ's API to allow for accepting nested records much more often than now, see:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11998

Currently, this isn't possibly mainly because it's very hard to emulate in all dialects, including the many dialects that don't natively support expressions on row value expressions.

jOOQ has the [`Functions::nullOnAllNull`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Functions.html#nullOnAllNull(org.jooq.Function2)) API, which allows you to do what you want entirely in the client:

```java
context.select(
  row(PRE_PLEADING.ID, PRE_PLEADING.TITLE)
  .mapping(nullOnAllNull(ReceivedPleadingSummary::new)))
.from(...)
```

That should do the trick?